# Best way to get/set columns dynamically from a SQLite3 database?

Tags: php, sqlite

...or I really need to create a class for each Table? then.. everytime i changes table structure i need to update the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...thanks all, ended up writting my own magic class:

[DBIntrd - Simple PHP framework for SQLite3 databases](http://dann.com.br/dbintrd-framework-sqlite-to-php-objects/)

Tired of spending time writting a bunch of code to create PHP classes & methods for SQLite tables?

DBIntrd is magic way to dinamically instance objects and persists data at SQLite3 tables..

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ORM (Object-relational mapper) such as Eloquent, which is included in [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent), and then just create an model (class) for each table in your database. Eloquent automatically maps each field into a PHP object. If you haven't ever used an ORM, I highly recommend you check out Laravel... it's what made me stick with PHP and I do almost all my projects using Laravel. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to BakerStreet Response.

Eloquent fits your needs as the ORM itself will fetch all the columns you specify if you leave it as default. By default the drivers that it works with are: mysql, postgreSQL, and Sqlite.

Eloquent itself can be downloaded without Laravel being involved.

Please refer to Jeffrey Way's Laracast for instruction:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/how-to-use-eloquent-outside-of-laravel